# Finite $\lim f(x)$ but unbounded $f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f(x) is continuous on $[2, +\infty)$, differentiable on $(2, +\infty)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} f(x)$ is finite. Then there exists $c > 2$ such that $f'(x)$ is bounded on $[c, + \infty)$.

How to find counterexample for this statement?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! It's most helpful if you provide a brief description of what you've tried so that we know how to help. Anyway I've given an outline of the solution in an intuitive sense. See if you can find the answer using that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple example is $$f(x)=\frac{\cos(x^3)}{x}\ ,$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0\ ,$$
but
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left[-3x\sin(x^3)-\frac{\cos(x^3)}{x^2}\right]$$
doesn't exist and $f'$ is unbounded.

Comment: But  $2 sin(x^2)$ is bounded, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, my bad... Now should be fine...

Comment: Wow, such a simple change. Thank you for your example.

Answer (score 0):

First you create bounding functions for $f$ to make sure that it has a limit. Then you make $f$ oscillate faster and faster between the upper and lower bounding functions so that its derivative won't be bounded.

Comment: I don't understand: if the function is oscillating, how could it have limit?

Comment: @Blastic: Read my answer carefully. There's a "between" you missed.

Comment: So, I should make 3 functions: 2 limiting and 1 in between?

Comment: @Blastic: Yes that's the easy way to do it, since you can use the squeeze theorem to show that the in-between function has a limit, and yet it has the freedom to move around between the two bounding functions.

Comment: OK. Let's the upper bound be $exp(-x)$ and the lower one be $-exp(-x)$. How to deduce the function in between? I suspect it should include some trigonometric term in it.

Comment: @Blastic: Yes that's a good approach to have the bounding functions symmetric about the limit, but perhaps you want them to go to 0 slower so that you don't have to oscillate too fast. Use a trigonometric function that oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ faster and faster and try multiplying it to one of the bounding functions.

Comment: I've managed to get oscillating derivatives. $f = exp(-x) * sin(exp^2(x))$. How to make it to move even faster?

Comment: @Blastic: Well if you make the thing inside the $\sin$ grow faster, then it will oscillate faster. And instead of using $\exp(-x)$ you could have used $1/x$.

Comment: It looks like $f=sin((exp(x))^{exp(x)})/x$ has unbounded derivative. Thank you, user, for you help!

Comment: @Blastic: That's correct, though $x \mapsto \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$ would do.